# Arch linux installation messed up, computer currently on hold

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I am currently following this tutorial to install arch linux
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_f8pnXIrF8&ab_channel=ColtFoxy

at 22:23

What I have done following the guide:
mapped the drive using cgdisk into

sda

|-sda1 0 part /mnt/boot

|-sda2 0 part [SWAP]

|-sda3 0 part /mnt

|-sda4 0 part /mnt/home

*All was well until I got a typo typing in the command: *pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel linux li(n)ux-headers*, I missed the (n) and freaked out. The process continued. and goes on to synchronize package databases. core, extra, and community.
*I notice the typo after the process. I freaked out and pressed ctrl+z on:**

Enter a selection (default=all):^Z

[1] + 1558 suspended pacstrap -i /mnt base base/devel linux liux-headers

*I tried again, with correct spelling twice on 148 root@archiso and 1 root@archiso
both responded with:*

mount /mnt/sys: sys already mounted on /sys
==>ERROR: failed to setup chroot /mnt

*I want to keep it neat and use the least amount of word, but thank you in advance!*

Comment: Look through here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide . Perhaps you can see something the video does not make clear.

Comment: Please don't follow random youtube videos when you are installing the Linux distribution with the best and most detailed official documentation available! Just start over, and follow the link Stephen Boston gave you above, and follow it _exactly_.

Comment: Considering how early in the install you are, @terdon's advice makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you guys! will do, I found that there are a lot of different ways to partition the disk. on arch wiki it teaches fdisk. I have also seen gdisk and cgdisk(in the video) are there any differences?

Answer (score 0):

People like to be purists and say that the ArchWiki is gospel, but if a video is updated enough it doesn't hurt to follow it for an interactive way to go through the install, that being said, you should check the wiki too and try to understand what you are doing at each step.

By what you said here you just suspended the execution of pacstrap (`^-Z`) and using `fg` you could have resumed what you were doing, but since it might have already run some operations it may have broken something that would "bite your behind" later on. I would advise you to start over too and be a bit more carefull with your spelling.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!! I googled that "fg' is a command that brings processes to the foreground? I have shutdown the computer already. However would you let please me know what will "fg" do in that situation?

Comment: `^-z` suspends the process and sends it to the background, `fg` continues execution and brings the process to the foreground. In the case you mentioned you would be back at the instance of pacstrap that you started and it would give you an error message related to the package you misspelled, Probably would have been fine to run it again with correct spelling, but since it is right at the beggining of the install starting over with clean partitions is best.

Don't forget to mark an answer as a solution if it answers your question.